# Windows x86 Cumulative Update causing the PC to go into Automatic Repair

Tags: windows, windows-10, updates, automatic-maintenance

My Grandpa's ASUS Laptop is running on Windows 10 32 bit and recently he received a notification requesting him to install some updates.The updates are Windows cumulative update for x86 architecture (Windows 10 Version 1607 for x86-based Systems (KB4057142)) and some windows defender security updates. The notification also said that your OS might stop working if the updates aren't installed so he clicked on install. The install was successfull after which the system restarted to finish the installation. As soon as the system resttarted the system went into automatic repair mode (The system was not able to boot normally after installing the Update) Automatic repair was unable to repair the pc and under advanced option resetting the PC was only possible, there were not restore points so I had to completely reset the system, deleting all data and resinstalling a fresh version of Windows 10. He came to me and I was able to reset the PC (Deleting everything without keeping Personal Data) and again tried to install the updtae, and this time also the system went into automatic repair mode. I don't know what's the problem and how to solve it!

Comment: "the updates are Windows cumulative update for x86 architecture and some windows defender security updates. ' - You will have to tell us which specific updates they were.  There have been dozens of cumulative updates for Windows 10 over the last 2 years.  When you indicate you "reset" the system, please be specific, if you actually mean restart the system please use the correct terminology.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't remember the specific terms but I will try my best!

Comment: If you have already removed everything, including your personal files, it's time to install the current version of Windows 10.  The update that is failing belongs to 1607, which is not the current version of Windows, that would be 1709.  *What you need to do is determine if the laptop will support 1709, and if it does support it, install that.*

Comment: "The notification also said that your OS might stop working if the updates aren't installed" - This seems dubious.  So either the notification said something else entirely, or it wasn't a legitimate notification, which means a fresh installation of Windows 10 is in order.  Download the current ISO for 1709 and install it.  This isn't really an answer to your question since I have no way of knowing if this will actually work due to the lack of quality detailed information.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't have enough info cause my Grandpa encountered all the notifications so I will try to reinstall Windows 10.